# Why doesn't my sprinkler system work after making a repair splice in the wire?

Tags: electrical, sprinkler-system, irrigation

I hit my sprinkler wire with a shovel while digging a trench for Termidor (for the exterminator). The cable is completely worn so that I can't read anything on it except that it's 18/5 Type CL2. It has a red, yellow, green, white, and blue wire. I bought this thermostat wire [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0069F4HHC) because I thought it was the same wire.  I spliced the broken point with this wire and triple checked the connections. The sprinkler doesn't run. I connected the controller to the broken point on the wire to make sure there were no loose connections and it runs perfectly, so my issue is with the new wire or splice. It runs under a sidewalk so I want to avoid needing to run all new wire. Anything I can do here?

Comment: What type of splices are you using?

Comment: For now, just waterproof wire nuts to test but I think I'm going to do a Nasa splice once I have it working. I do know this splice work because I was able to connect the old common wire and zone 1 wire this way and it worked. I would have done this with all of them but the other wires were beyond repair for several feet.

Comment: Off hand would say one or more wires not splicing well.  Having same trouble splicing an antenna rotor wire, inside a small hole.

Comment: Are you sure the wire is not cut elsewhere as well?

Comment: Where you hit the wire, look (and excavate gently) both sides. When the wire was stretched it may have partly broken at a nearby point. You can temporarily connect a  group of wires at the new join to see if it is just one wire or the whole group broken. If all broken, will have to excavate and find and splice across the break.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution provided is not related to the question. As such, it offers little value to the community.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that, in this particular case, the splice was done correctly and there was no damage to the wire on either end of the splice. However, while splicing, the controller fell from a relatively high height and seems to have broken. When using a multimeter on the volts setting, I placed one probe on the common and another probe on the selected zone. The multimeter showed no results. I tested the old controller and it was working correctly (though I replaced that controller due to faulty display). I am purchasing a new one.